# How to make Visual Studio 2010 the default code editor in Expression Blend 4

Tags: windows, visual-studio, expression-blend

Expression Blend 3 opens VS2008 as the default editor.

Expression Blend 4 uses an internal, notepad-like editor instead of using VS2010/2008.
How can I fix this?

edit: it actually finds VS2010 via the project main menu but does not open it in the context of event handling (Workflow via element Properties -> Events -> ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Projects and check the box for using Visual Studio Standard or higher to edit event handler code (or something along those lines).  Now Blend will open event handling code in VS.  Just an aside, if you create custom behavior's it will still open those in Blend.